MediaStreamTrack doesn’t play video on HTMLVideoElement in mediasoup
i am consuming from following code on front end nextjs
const consume = async (producerId: string) => {
    console.log('producerId', producerId);
    // console.log('device rtpCapabilities', device.rtpCapabilities);

    if (!device.rtpCapabilities) {
        console.error('Device RTP capabilities are not available');
        return;
    }
      socket.emit('consume', { producerId, rtpCapabilities: device.rtpCapabilities }, async (params: ConsumeParams) => {
        console.log('recvTransport test', recvTransport);
        console.log('recvTransport params', params);
        const consumer: mediasoupClient.types.Consumer = await recvTransport.consume({
          id: params.id,
          producerId: params.producerId,
          kind: params.kind,
          rtpParameters: params.rtpParameters,
          // paused:true,
          paused: true
        });
        
        console.log('consumer 77777777', consumer);
        // Check if the consumer.track is valid
        if (!consumer.track) {
          console.error('consumer.track is undefined or null');
          return;
        }
    
        // Check if the track is a video track and its state
        if (consumer.track.kind === 'video' && consumer.track.readyState === 'live') {
          console.log('Received a valid live video track:', consumer.track);
    
          const stream = new MediaStream();
          stream.addTrack(consumer.track);
    
          // Check if the stream contains video tracks
          if (stream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
            console.log('Stream contains video tracks:', stream.getVideoTracks());
    
            // Add stream to remote streams
            setRemoteStreams((prev) => [...prev, stream]);
    
            socket.emit('consumer-resume', {
              serverConsumerId: params.id,
            });
          } else {
            console.error('No video tracks in stream:', stream);
          }
        } else {
          console.error('Invalid track or track not live:', consumer.track.readyState, consumer.track.kind);
        }
      });
    };

below is screen shot as well with log consumer 7777 still it is showing _paused false although i set paused as true

below is screenshot for mediastream which i am getting from other participants still in video element showing nothing

